# Different language for debug and release mode in iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, debugging

I'm developing ann app that supports Swedish language that is not my native language. so if i put all the text in swedish from starting than it will be very difficult for me to debug the app.
So is there a way that i can debug my app in English and release in Swedish? Like put text in .plist and check for debug mode?but i don't really know how to do that.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use localisation.
take a look at the following tutorial:
It was very helpful for me:
     http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

Comment: I'm not supporting localisation, but just two different language for debug and release mode.

Comment: So create to plist and do:
NSString *path ;
#ifdef DEBUG
   path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"swedishTextPList"
                                                         ofType:@"plist"]; 
#else
 path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"englishTextPList"
                                                         ofType:@"plist"];
#endif

Comment: could you please give me a sort example?

Comment: Sorry. was pressing enter before completing the answer

Comment: Thanks dude edit your answer and put that code in comment into answer.